# Merging two dataframes by adding column and then updating existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

Given two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, I want to take the last column of `df2` and add it to `df1` based on column `'a'` they both have.

That is for every row in `df2`, if `df1['a']` has is, then I want to add it to the new column. The rows of `df1['a']` that aren't in `df2['a']` we set N/A. If there is a value in `df2['a']` that isn't in `df1['a']`, we ignore it

Additionally, while adding a column, I was hoping to update `df1['b']` and `df1['c']` to the values of `df2['b']` and `df2['c']`.

For the first part, this the best I've gotten

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='a')
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('a')
```

This needlessly create doubles and I even update

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7],'c':[8,9,10],'new_column_from_df2':[11,12,13]})
df1['a'].to_frame().merge(df2, how='left', on='a')
```

Output:

```
Out[190]: 
   a    b    c  new_column_from_df2
0  1  NaN  NaN                  NaN
1  2  5.0  8.0                 11.0
2  3  6.0  9.0                 12.0
```

Note the last row of `df2` being ignored/excluded because it is not in `df1['a']`. Columns `'b'` and `'c'` are "updated" with `df2` values.